# Android Beacon Library class diagram?

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android, beacon

I'm using the Android Beacon Library for my project and I'm wondering if there's a class diagram or a UML diagram of the classes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no, there is no published class diagram at this time.

As an open source project, we would welcome a submission of one.  Lots of tools can generate them from java classes.